# How to insert a message with an attachment using Gmail API (Java)

Tags: java, email, gmail, gmail-api

I use Gmail API via Java client library and I've found out that Gmail API `insert(java.lang.String userId, com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message content)` method inserts only files smaller than 5Mb.

I tried to use `Insert insert(java.lang.String userId, com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message content, com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent mediaContent)` to insert a message with a file (size 10MB).

```
MimeMessage email = GmailAPI.createEmail("toXXX@gmail.com", "fromYYY@gmail.com", "subject", "message body");
FileContent content = new FileContent("message/rfc822", new File("C:\\Users\\user\\someFile"));
Message message = createMessageWithEmail(email);
message = service.users().messages().insert(userId, message, mediaContent).execute();
```

CreateEmail is simple method from quickstart:

```
   public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to,
                                              String from,
                                              String subject,
                                              String bodyText)
                throws MessagingException {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);

            email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(to));
            email.setSubject(subject);
            email.setText(bodyText);
            return email;
        }
```

The message appeared in my email box but without the file.

**What's wrong here?**

**UPD1:** Inserting with media content, inserts only an email without an attachment. I think I use it in a wrong way.

Comment: As far as I remember you can only send attachments < 5MB and perhaps this limit applies to using Gmail API as well.

Comment: @menteith I guess insert method has the same limitations as send: Maximum file size: 35MB; 
Accepted Media MIME types: message/rfc822.
Ssource:https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to use resumable upload using java library (the same idea via REST):

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(message.getRaw());
Insert insertReq;
Message content = new Message();
content.setLabelIds(message.getLabelIds());
try {
    insertReq = gmail.users().messages().insert(account, content,
        new ByteArrayContent("message/rfc822", bytes, 0, bytes.length));
    helper.execute(insertReq, task.getPartnerID(), task.isUnderWhiteLable());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.error("Failed to insert a message with resumable upload message", e);
}
```

The method's description turned out to be quite understandable but post factum. I have no idea why the description is so poor:

```
/**                                                                                                                                                                                                
 * Directly inserts a message into only this user's mailbox similar to IMAP APPEND, bypassing most                                                                                                 
 * scanning and classification. Does not send a message.                                                                                                                                           
 *                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 * Create a request for the method "messages.insert".                                                                                                                                              
 *                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 * This request holds the parameters needed by the the gmail server.  After setting any optional                                                                                                   
 * parameters, call the {@link Insert#execute()} method to invoke the remote operation.                                                                                                            
 *                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 * <p>                                                                                                                                                                                             
 * This method should be used for uploading media content.                                                                                                                                         
 * </p>                                                                                                                                                                                            
 *                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 * @param userId The user's email address. The special value me can be used to indicate the authenticated user.                                                                                    
 *        [default: me]                                                                                                                                                                            
 * @param content the {@link com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message} media metadata or {@code null} if none                                                                                   
 * @param mediaContent The media HTTP content or {@code null} if none.                                                                                                                             
 * @return the request                                                                                                                                                                             
 * @throws java.io.IOException if the initialization of the request fails                                                                                                                          
 */                                                                                                                                                                                                
public Insert insert(java.lang.String userId, com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message content, com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent mediaContent) throws java.io.IOException {
  Insert result = new Insert(userId, content, mediaContent);                                                                                                                                       
  initialize(result);                                                                                                                                                                              
  return result;                                                                                                                                                                                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert emails larger than 5MB you must use either *multipart upload* or *resumable upload* (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads) for details).

In Java Gmail API client library, 2-argument version of [`insert`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/blob/master/clients/google-api-services-gmail/v1/1.26.0/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.java#L3348) method sends a *simple upload* request, which can upload up to 5MB. To send a *resumable upload* request, use 3-argument version of [`insert`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/blob/master/clients/google-api-services-gmail/v1/1.26.0/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.java#L3374) method. Using *resumable upload* you can insert up to 50MB.

Here is a method that inserts `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` using *resumable upload*:

```java
import com.google.api.client.http.ByteArrayContent;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
```

```java
private Message insertMessage(Gmail gmail, String userId, MimeMessage mimeMessage, List<String> labelIds, String threadId) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    // Create Message instance containing email message metadata
    Message metadata = new Message()
            .setLabelIds(labelIds)
            .setThreadId(threadId);

    // Create byte array containing email message data (in RFC 2822 format)
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mimeMessage.writeTo(baos);
    ByteArrayContent rawMessageBytes = new ByteArrayContent("message/rfc822", baos.toByteArray());

    return gmail.users().messages()
            .insert(userId, metadata, rawMessageBytes)
            .setInternalDateSource("dateHeader")  // The GMail internal message time is based on the Date header in the email, when valid.
            .execute();
}
```